# Changing Dates as per production shift timings in R

Tags: r, date, datetime-format, lubridate

i want to change the date of the data entry based on timestamp. Basically, the company starts its operations at 7:00am in morning and works till 6:59am next day. this entire duration is counted as 1 day.
So basically 19th Nov 2020 would mean starting 19-11-2020 07:00 to 20-11-2020 06:59

i have this dataset

```
structure(list(Timestamp = structure(c(1593714765.03054, 1593714824.99918, 
1593714884.96776, 1593714945.01468, 1593715005.01454, 1593715064.98314, 
1593715125.03002, 1593715185.18608, 1593715244.99822, 1593715304.96657
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Asia/Kolkata"), Date = structure(c(18446, 
18446, 18446, 18446, 18446, 18446, 18446, 18446, 18446, 18446
), class = "Date"), Time = c("00:02", "00:03", "00:04", "00:05", 
"00:06", "00:07", "00:08", "00:09", "00:10", "00:11"), `HCM 18` = c(7, 
8, 7, 8, 7, 7, 8, 7, 8, 7), `HCM 19` = c(8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 8, 
8, 8, 8), `HCM 20` = c(7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 4, 8, 7, 7), `HCM 21` = c(8, 
7, 8, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8), `HCM 22` = c(8, 7, 8, 7, 7, 8, 7, 
8, 7, 7), `HCM 23` = c(8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8), `HCM 24` = c(7, 
7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 4, 0), `HCM 25` = c(8, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 
7, 8, 8), `HCM 54` = c(7, 8, 8, 7, 6, 8, 7, 8, 8, 7), `HCM 55` = c(8, 
7, 8, 7, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 7), `HCM 56` = c(8, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 7, 
8, 8, 7), `HCM 57` = c(8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 7, 8), `HCM 58` = c(8, 
8, 7, 8, 7, 8, 7, 8, 7, 8), `HCM 59` = c(8, 1, 6, 8, 8, 7, 8, 
8, 7, 8), `HCM 60` = c(8, 7, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

So now i need to change the date for time less than 7:00am to previous day.

i want to do this in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ITime` class from the `data.table` package. The `ITime` can store the time of day as the integer number of seconds in the day. Create a variable `open_time` to store the number of seconds at 7:00 AM. Then, for each `Timestamp` (converted to an `ITime`), see if the time is less than the `open_time`, and if it is, use `Date - 1` instead of `Date`. To demonstrate, a new column is created (`NewDate`).

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

open_time <- as.ITime(as.POSIXct("07:00", format = "%H:%M"))

df %>%
  mutate(NewTime = as.ITime(Timestamp),
         NewDate = if_else(
           NewTime < open_time,
           Date - 1,
           Date
         )
  )
```